# 407 Proxy Authentication error - Unirest Java 8

Tags: java, http, unirest

Hi everyone i'm so hopeless so ask you guys.
I'm trying to do a simple HTTP request but with my proxies I get 407 error code.
I use Unirest and Java 8.

```
 Unirest.config().proxy(host, port, usernameProxy, passwordProxy);   
 HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.post(url).asJson();
 String body = response.getBody().toString();
```

That's it, my url is private but i wrote it like this: "https://myurl.com/?param1=param&param2....
It works proxyless but i'm stuck with proxies.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the **proxy server expects for the proxy credentials within the Headers**, which **`Unirest`** doesn't seem to propagate.

The header must specifically contain the `"Proxy-Authorization"` key in order to the handshake be even started.

```
String proxyCred= "user:password"; 
String baseCred= Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(proxyCred.getBytes());
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + baseCred); // the proxy server needs this
```

This solution uses the **`Basic`** mechanism; It may not work, as the proxy may expect another type of authentication. You'll know which one is by reading the `Proxy-Authenticate` header within the server's response.

If the communication is not secured (*HTTP and not HTTP**S***), you could read the response by sniffing the packet with some tool such as *WireShark*. Once you locate the `407 packet`, you could read inside the `Proxy-Authenticate` value and modify your authorization method according do it.